# How to print a custom message in TeXstudio "Messages" terminal?

Tags: macros, texstudio, terminal-output

Consider the `Process exited normally` message after each successful compilation,

[image]

I would like to know how to create a command that can type messages like this in TeXstudio "Messages" terminal?

I need two versions of the command: one I can use inside a package file `*.sty` and the other to be used in my typical `*.tex` file after `\begin{document}`

**P.S. I am using TeXstudio on Windows 10**

Comment: That is impossible as stated: TeXstudio controls what goes here, not TeX, at least in the default configuration. You can change this in the options (Build → Show stdout: → Always (If not redirected > /dev/null)), but then you will the the normal command line output, which will go by rather quickly. What you can do is write something to the `log` file. If it is a warning or an error (in the usual format), TeXstudio will find it and display it in the Log tab, right next to the Messages tab.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because answered in comments and no follow-up of OP.